# Как определить, что при движении карты изменился или нет набор точек видимой области?

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Мне надо определить, изменился ли набор точек в видимой области на карте при движении карты, или изменении ее масштаба. Есть ли для этого какой-то Yandex API способ? Или надо придумывать свою логику вроде сравнения массивов точек до и после движения карты?

true: да - после изменения масштаба или положения карты набор точек изменился, и если да, то я буду его получать.

false: нет - после изменения масштаба или положения карты набор точек не изменился, и ничего делать не надо

По сути мне надо получить значение true или false при реакции на это событие:

```
myMap.events.add(['boundschange','datachange','objecttypeschange'], function(e){
тут логика определения точек попадающих в видимую область карты и взаимодействие с ним
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Готового метода в API для получения объектов в видимой области - нет, но есть набор методов [geoQuery](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/GeoQueryResult-docpage/?from=SO). Например, с помощью `searchInside()` можно найти объекты (точки), которые целиком входят в другой (полигон видимой области карты).

Кроме того [LoadingObjectManager](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/loading-object-manager/about-docpage/?from=SO) позволяет загружать на карту только те объекты, которые попадают в видимую область, и работать всегда только с ними.